# How can I have multiple sets of views per controller in Grails?

Tags: grails

I'm rewriting the views for my site but I'd still like to have the originals running because the rewrite is missing features. Is there a way for me to have both and depending upon the URL pick one or the other? They'll be sharing the same domain and controller classes.

For example, http://localhost/app/* goes to the original views and http://localhost/app/test/* goes to the new views.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The context path when using the render function uses the name of the controller by default.
What you could do is add a parameter in your url mapping, is this satisfying ? :

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/test/$controller/$action?" {
            indent = "newviewfolder/"
        }
    }
}
```

And, in a controller method

```
class RandomController {
    render(${params.indent}"viewname", model [:], params)
}
```

Comment: That could work if I use a different layout for the test pages. I'll try it later. Do you think there's a way without modifying the controller?

Comment: Well, either way you have to create a different controller method, or a different controller altogether. Sorry for the delay by the way.